# RSpec Routing Error in test but not in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I have a route in a app I'm working on, it looks like this...

```
  match ":place_id/:id", :controller => "companies", :action => "show", :place_id => /\S{2}/
```

So in my browser I can navigate to this URL.

mylocalmachine/gb/some-company

In the server log its all good.

```
Started GET "/gb/some-company" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-30 17:44:52 +0100
Processing by CompaniesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"place_id"=>"gb", "id"=>"some-company"}
```

But in a controller spec I am trying to test this route and its behaviour.

```
get "/gb/some-company"
```

But I get this error

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"companies", :action=>"gb/some-comapny"}
```

NOTE: I have tried putting this route at the top of the routes.rb file to see if the test works but with no luck. Also all other specs are passing. Any ideas where I might be going wrong would be appreciated.

UPDATE: This is what the test looks like...

```
params_from(:get, "/gb/some-company").should == {:controller => "companies", :action => "show", :country_id => "gb", :id => "some-company"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because RSpec controller tests match your request directly to the action name of the described controller.

Your test probably looks like this

```
describe CompaniesController do
  it "does something" do
    get "/gb/some-company"
  end
end
```

If you replace your `get "/gb/some-company"` with

`get :show, {place_id: 'gb', id: 'some-company'}`

I'm sure it'll work how you want it to work.

If you want to actually make the request as "/gb/some-company" through RSpec, you might want to look at request specs.

They will allow you to do something like this

```
describe "Company stuff" do
  it "is awesome"
    get "/gb/some-company"
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

I'm assuming now, based on your updated question, that you're using an old version of RSpec. RSpec 2 does not currently have a `params_from` method

In any case, based on what you want, you want to use `routing specs`

The spec you want would look something like this in RSpec 2

```
describe "Company matching" do
  it "matches the routes" do
    expect(:get => '/gb/some-company').to route_to(:controller => "companies", :action => "show", :country_id => "gb", :id => "some-company")
  end
end
```

I'm not 100% sure how it would look in older versions of RSpec as I can't seem to find their docs.

Comment: Yeah this works thanks, the test is actually to ensure that the params are correctly extracted from the URL. I have updated the question to show the actual test, is there a better way I can write the test for this?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after, I am in the process of upgrading the app from Rails 2-3 and RSpec to version 2. Thanks for your help!